# Substitute for if(isset($_GET['page'])) and header('Location:'.$url); in PHP for JSP

Tags: php, jsp-tags

Please help me convert the following PHP code into JSP

```
<?php

$url = $_REQUEST['url'];
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    if( $_GET['page'] == '' )
    {
        header('Location:'.$url);
    }
    else
    {
        $_REQUEST['page'] = $_REQUEST['page'];
        header('Location: '.$url.'?page=#'.$_REQUEST['page']);
    }
}

?>
```

I am unable to find substitute for Isset function in PHP and header location tag in PHP used for redirection in JSP

Comment: How about you break the problem down into "how to check whether a query parameter is set" and "how to redirect in JSP"? It's the *functionality* you're looking for, not the "equivalent code".

Comment: ok then tell me redirect code for JSP ....

Comment: DO NOT write such code in JSP. It's Java, not PHP. Please, do it in the Controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not good in JSP ..Any way i tried. Probably this is the thing you want:

```
<%
String url, page;
url = request.getParameter("url");
page = request.getParameter("page");
if(page)
{
    if( page == '' )
    {
        response.sendRedirect(url);
    }
    else
    {
        response.sendRedirect(url + "?page=#"+page));
    }
}
%>
```

Comment: appreciate your concern THANKs for help will try this :)

Comment: Error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Boolean` in Eclipse 2011. How `page` be treaded as boolean in java? Have you tried @Sabari? Not work for me.

Comment: @NickDong seems to be an issue with Eclipse. Please check here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351345. Can you try with latest version of eclipse